# Is it safe/good practice to always add cmake_minimum_required at the top of CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

CMake newbie here, sorry for asking something too trivial...

Is it safe to always add `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION ...)` on top CMakeLists.txt file? Suppose there is a one big project dividided into subproject, each one with it's own CMakeLists.txt file.

CMakeLists.txt file in this case looks something like

```
add_subdirectory(subproject_1)
...
add_subdirectory(subproject_n)
```

should `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION ...)` still be added on top? Should it be skipped?
After all, the work is done by subproject CMakeList.txt files, so I do not see a reason to do it, unless "everybody does it" which I am not sure is the case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is always safe, though it will be annoying to go through and bump all of the versions when you want to upgrade your baseline (which should happen frequently). You should use a consistent policy set within a single project.

For those subprojects which are intended to be buildable standalone (i.e. they have `project()` at the top), it is a hard requirement. The first statement executed by CMake should *always* be `cmake_minimum_required`.

Comment: What about sub-projects that are not that are not standalone. Do they inherit the minimum version/policy of parent?